# Creating Classified add site with dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need to create classified add site with dotnetnuke is there good open source module or suggest a good approach,quick tutorial

thanks to all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, all of the high quality and complicated modules are pay.  DotNetJedi has a good classifieds module.

http://www.dotnetjedi.com/Store/tabid/53/uc/info/ItemID/8/Default.aspx

A quick codeplex search revealed this:

http://simplyclassified.codeplex.com/

But the links provided in the site don't work so I have no idea if it's good or not.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for what you're wanting to do, but [Property Agent from Ventrian](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/PropertyAgent.aspx) is a great, flexible and powerful module that might meet your needs. It isn't free but does come with Source code for a very reasonable subscription.